# How to merge elements of nested list for specific words

Tags: python

Really hoping someone can help with what is probably an easy issue but am struggling as a newbie to python.

I have the below nested list:

```
[['bob', 'smith', 'green'],
['jon', 'mc', 'donnell', 'red'],
['fred', 'thomas', 'blue'],
['jim', 'mc', 'donald', 'orange']]
```

I would like to iterate over it to end with something like the below to write to csv to open in excel:

```
[['bob', 'smith', 'green'],
['jon', 'mcdonnell', 'red'],
['fred', 'thomas', 'blue'],
['jim', 'mcdonald', 'orange']]
```

I have tried a for loop with an if statement including 'mc' but it just ends with e.g. 'mcdonnell' in the line only.

I tried to add the code but I kept getting an error saying indent with 4 spaces which I did but it still didn't like it so not sure what I was missing there.

Comment: Please add the code so that we can get clear understanding of what is wrong.  In a new line write ``` your code here ```.

Comment: Can you please show for loop you coded?

Comment: Also in you final output do you want to ignore all the "mc" in lists ?

Comment: Do you always want to concatenate the next immediate word after 'mc' to it?

Comment: What is the exact rule that tells you how to get from one of the input lists to the desired output list? Do you care about prefixes other than "mc"? Do you care if there is more than one in a given input?

Comment: thanks for the comments of assistance. Clearly lots to learn with Python and info needed to post on this forum. I am going to go with Ch3steR's comment at the moment as feel so close but will add the other info if required.Many thanks all.

Comment: _I tried to add the code but I kept getting an error_ Stack Overflow wouldn't let you paste the code? Can you just include it as normal text, and someone else will format it? Also, I feel it is important to mention that Stack Overflow is not a tutoring service, nor is it a substitute for guides or documentation.

Comment: @AMC thanks, I will post the code as normal text if I use for any future questions. Apologies if my question looked like I was looking for tutoring that was not my intention, I was hoping to get assistance with a specific element of code, but I will go back to searching the web. Thank you for the the information provided by all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```py
names = [['bob', 'smith', 'green'],
['jon', 'mc', 'donnell', 'red'],
['fred', 'thomas', 'blue'],
['jim', 'mc', 'donald', 'orange']]

for name in names:
    if name[1] == 'mc':
         concat_middle = name.pop(1) + name.pop(1)
         name.insert(1, concat_middle)
```

Comment: Many thanks Swetank Poddar
This worked for that script but I have others that have different strings that I need to merge some with spaces as mentioned above, I tried changing "if(len(name)) > 3:" for "if name == 'mc':" but it didn't change anything, I am thinking I am misunderstanding the code or useage?

Comment: Oh you want to merge the two indexes only if there's a "mc"? I have edited my answer for that!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want to concatenate the next immediate word after `'mc'` to it. You can try this using `iter` and taking advantage of `next`.

```
a=[['bob', 'smith', 'green'],
['jon', 'mc', 'donnell', 'red'],
['fred', 'thomas', 'blue'],
['jim', 'mc', 'donald', 'orange']]

[[i+next(it) if i=='mc' else i for i in it] for it in map(iter,a)]
```

---

Output:

```
[['bob', 'smith', 'green'],
 ['jon', 'mcdonnell', 'red'],
 ['fred', 'thomas', 'blue'],
 ['jim', 'mcdonald', 'orange']]
```

Comment: Many thanks Ch3steR
This worked although some of the elements I need to do the same to need a space between the merged strings, is there any easy way to add a space with code you supplied?

Comment: @freddy2020 Yes, just use `i+' '+next(it)` instead or clean way would be to use *f-strings*.

Comment: that worked, but not sure how to include in the script. I have the following:

for name_line in name_brief:
    name_split = name_line.split()
    name_brief_list.append(name_split)
    [[i + ' ' + next(it) if i == 'mc' else i for i in it] for it in map(iter, name_brief_list)]
    with open(get_namebrief_filename(), 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(name_brief_list)

And added the code you supplied as per above but the result in the spreadsheet still is in separate columns, do I have incorrect placement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the behaviour you desire: for a list of lists, you want to merge the 2nd and 3rd element of a list with 4 elements?

A verbose solution:

```py
for i, array in enumerate(array_of_arrays):
    if len(array) == 4:
        middle = array[1] + array[2]
        array_of_arrays[i] = [array[0], middle, array[3]]
```

Note I use Python's `enumerate` method, which returns an array as a pair of index and the respective element.